# TypeError while writing a datadictionary in PySpark

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, pyspark, typeerror

I'm trying to apply some simple functions to a Spark dataframe and write those results as a dictionary into a file.

Here is the base code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import countDistinct,col



spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkByExamples.com').getOrCreate();
data = [(1,"Aj",None,"ABC"), (2,"Kishore","N","DEF"), (3,"Kishore","P",None),(4,"Naveen","N","XYZ")]
columns = ["empid","empfname","emplname","empjobcode"]



df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=columns)
df.show()




finallist = []
class func:
    def __init__(self, columnname):
        self.columnname = columnname
def process(columnlist):
    for x in columnlist:
        dfnull = df.where(F.col(x.columnname).isNull())
        dfnotnull = df.filter(col(x.columnname).isNotNull())
        dfdistinct = df.select(x.columnname).distinct()
        
        datadictionary = [(x.columnname,{"Null count":dfnull.count(),
                                         "Percentage of Null":(dfnull.count()/df.count())*100,
                                        "Not-null count":dfnotnull.count(),
                                        "Percentage of Not-null":(dfnotnull.count()/df.count())*100,
                                        "Distinct value count":dfdistinct.count(),
                                        "Percentage of Distinct value":(dfdistinct.count()/df.count())*100})]
        print(datadictionary)



finallist.append(func("empid"))
finallist.append(func("empfname"))
finallist.append(func("emplname"))
finallist.append(func("empjobcode"))
```

Now, I tried to write the dictionary I created from this function into a file, using this code:

```
file = open('New.txt', 'w')  
file.write(process(finallist))
file.close()
```

An error popped up like this:

```
[('empid', {'Null count': 0, 'Percentage of Null': 0.0, 'Not-null count': 4, 'Percentage of Not-null': 100.0, 'Distinct value count': 4, 'Percentage of Distinct value': 100.0})]
[('empfname', {'Null count': 0, 'Percentage of Null': 0.0, 'Not-null count': 4, 'Percentage of Not-null': 100.0, 'Distinct value count': 3, 'Percentage of Distinct value': 75.0})]
[('emplname', {'Null count': 1, 'Percentage of Null': 25.0, 'Not-null count': 3, 'Percentage of Not-null': 75.0, 'Distinct value count': 3, 'Percentage of Distinct value': 75.0})]
[('empjobcode', {'Null count': 1, 'Percentage of Null': 25.0, 'Not-null count': 3, 'Percentage of Not-null': 75.0, 'Distinct value count': 4, 'Percentage of Distinct value': 100.0})]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [73], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 file = open('New.txt', 'w')  
----> 2 file.write(process(finallist))
      3 file.close()



TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None
```

So, I guess what's happening here is it executes the **process()** function with finallist as argument but then finds the datatype of the same function is null. **What should I do so that I obtain a similar result for all 4 columns like above but all of those written into the file?**. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your process function doesn't return anything, so you get None. You need to return something in your function (something like return datadictionary). The print function just prints to console, but does not return anything

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. The error is now mitigated but a small problem in written file. I tried using return datadictionary but it returns only the "emp id" column as result. When I remove one indentation, it returns only "empjobcode" column.

Comment: You need to put the return after the for loop. The problem is that you need to concat the diferent df you are creating in each iteration (datadictionary) over one df, and return this one